# How to setup proxy in Create React APP for builtin PHP Server?

Tags: php, create-react-app, http-proxy

I just want to run php built in server in Create React App.

I was trying multiple things nothing is working.

I've tried adding `"proxy"` to package.json also adding proxy manually:

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api/',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:4000/',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

I run my server with:

```
php -S localhost:4000 -t ./api
```

Api directory have index.php file. and I've never see the request in console. When I open the app that sent request to /api all I see is:

```
Error occured while trying to proxy: localhost:3000/api
```

and 504 (Gateway Timeout).

when I open http://localhost:4000/ everything is working fine. (it's JSON-RPC service that show error because there are no POST data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution on [GitHub issue](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/21):

You need to use IP address for proxy to work:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:4000 -t ./api
```

It will also work when using 127.0.0.1:4000 as address.